# Defining a domain for a complex number

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the given complex number,

$w=\frac{z+i}{z^2+1}$

which I rewrite in the form:

$w=\frac{x}{x^2+2ixy-y^2-1}+\frac{i(y+1)}{x^2+2ixy-y^2-1}$

When defining its domain of definition, I look for the zeros of the denominator and define x and y as existing elsewhere than at these zeros.

This gives the proposed definition $\mathscr{D}_w:\{x,y\in \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C} \  \backslash \{i(x+1),i(x-1)\} \}$.

But I am not sure that x and y can exist in $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ at the same time. So I am not sure here. Is this correct notation, or should it be re-written?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathscr{D}_w= \mathbb{C} \  \backslash \{i(x+1),i(x-1)\} \}$
is not correct. The domain should not involve the variable $x$.

$z^{2}=-i$ if and only if $z =\pm \frac {i-1} {\sqrt 2}$ so the doamin is $\mathbb C \setminus \{\frac {i-1} {\sqrt 2},-\frac {i-1} {\sqrt 2}\}$.

For the revised version of the question the domain is $\mathbb C \setminus \{-i,i\}$.

Comment: Why do you claim that the denominator of $\dfrac{z+i}{z^2+i}$ is $z^2+1$?

Comment: I wrote the number incorrectly,! All ok. It should be z^2+1